# Auto property synthesis warning with MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm creating a map for a specific location but it gave me a warning

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'coordinate'
>   declared in protocol 'MKAnnotation'

I got the message as shown in the picture below

[image: Picture]

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Your custom class must implement the coordinate property and a way to set its value. (**It’s recommended that you synthesize coordinate because it ensures that Map Kit can automatically update the map based on changes to the property.**) All that remains is to implement the custom initWithLocation: method, which is shown in Listing 6-2.
>
> Listing 6-2  Implementing the MyCustomAnnotation class

```
@implementation MyCustomAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate;
 
- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        coordinate = coord;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: It works, some of the things are not working but .. it worked!